# My project has 2 versions of the same dependency.One in the top level node_modules,the other one in child module node_modules.Child uses wrong version

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project that has 2 modules A and B, In module A, there is a module C with version 1.0.0 in the "dependency" of its package.json. In module B, there is module C with version 2.0.0 in the "dependency" of its package.json. The structure looks like below

```
-
 - A
  - C@1.0.0
 - B
  - C@2.0.0
```

I run `npm install`. C@1.0.0 is installed in the node_modules folder under module A, C@2.0.0 is installed under the root node_modules folder. Here is the folder structure

```
node_modules
 - A
  - node_modules
   - C@1.0.0
 - B
 - C@2.0.0
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why C@2.0.0 is not installed under B?
2. module A is not using C@1.0.0 which is installed in its own node_modules folder, instead, both module A and B use C@2.0.0 which is in the top level. How can I make it so that module A uses C@1.0.0 and module B uses C@2.0.0?

npm that I tested are 5.5.1, 6.9.2, 6.10.1

Comment: What evidence do you have to suggest that `A` is using `C@2.0.0`? I don't mean this sarcastically, but if your evidence is only circumstantial you might be going down the wrong rabbit hole here. Also why is this tagged [tag:yarnpkg] when you seem to be asking about this issue in specific versions of [tag:npm]?

Comment: To answer your first question, `npm` and `yarn` flatten the hierarchy of your project dependencies wherever it's able to unless there's a version conflict like in this case. When there is a version conflict, the latest version is the one that gets flattened.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I checked the built code, and I'm sure they both use the one in the top level, ignore the one in the child level